# how to build a model on top of the other on django

Tags: django

I have two models

- `Job Position`: It's the first object I create and represent a position in a company. `
- `Job offer`: It is related to `Job Position` through a foreign key and represent a job offer sent out for a specific `Job Position`

Each job position can have multiple job offers associated as you can send multiple job offers out.

Now, the `Job Position` model has some data such as "Salary" that I would like each `Job Offer` instance to inherit automatically BUT I would also like to be able to change at the `Job Offer` level (after negotiations).

For example:

1. A `jobposition` is open with `salary=50k`
2. 10 `joboffers` are sent out, each with `salary 50k`
3. After some negotiations, some `joboffers` are changed to `salary 80k`

Should `joboffers` have a salary field that I simply set equal to the salary `jobposition` when I create the object, or should I find a way to tie it initially within the model definition through some sort of foreign key but then make it flexibile?

```
class JobPosition(models.Model):
    ..
    salary=models.Integer()

class JobOffer(models.Model):
    position=models.ForeignKey(JobPosition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Comment: Can `JobPosition.salary` change over time? If yes (most likely), do you need to keep track of `JobPosition.salary` at a certain point in time where a `JobOffer` is created?

Comment: i might have to, yes

Comment: In that case I think this is what you want: `Should joboffers have a salary field that I simply set equal to the salary jobposition when I create the object`, but then have another field that would represent the final salary negotiated

Answer (score 0):

Your `JobOffer` models should have another field named `salary as you said sometimes salary value can be different from` JobPosition`

or you can some something like this:

```
class JobPosition(models.Model):
    ..
    salary=models.Integer()

class JobOffer(models.Model):
    position=models.ForeignKey(JobPosition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     salary=models.Integer()

    def job_position_salary(self):
        return self.position.salary
    ...
```